# Odd output from modulo division in Python

Tags: python

Given the following example:

```
seconds = totalTime % 60
minutes = (totalTime - seconds) % (60 ** 2)
hours = (totalTime - (minutes * 60)) / (60 ** 2)

finalTime = '{0:.0f}h {1:.0f}m {2:.0f}s'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

When I set totalTime to 7000 for example (a little under two hours), I get the following in return:

```
-55h 3360m 39s
```

Huh!?  This happens with any number numbers i give it...  Heres one more example if it help:

```
totalTime = 10000

-44h 2760m 39s
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are measuring the minutes in seconds.  To fix your code, you should divide `minutes` by 60:

```
minutes = (totalTime - seconds) % (60 ** 2) / 60
```

However, there are much easier ways to do this, for example

```
hours, seconds = divmod(totalTime, 60 ** 2)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `minutes` is actually measured in seconds. Do a divide by 60 in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the correct expressions would be:

```
seconds = totalTime % 60
minutes = (totalTime / 60) % 60
hours = totalTime / (60 ** 2)
```